# Problems with select tag logic rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-helpers

I have a **SoldHistory** model that belongs to a **Product** model and also have a **Branch** model. In the product show page theres a form to create **SoldHistory** *sold:integer* attribute. I am trying to add a select tag to the form that will pick objects from the **Branch** model.

```
<%= form_for [@product, @product.sold_histories.build, @branch = Branch.find(:all)] do |f| %>
    <%= f.label "Dispatch: "%>
    <%= f.number_field :sold %>
    <%= f.select :branch, options_from_collection_for_select(@branch, "id", "name") %>
    <%= f.submit "Enter" %>
  <% end %>
```

I tried this but it keeps saying could not find branch with id=all

Please what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are you assigning to @branch? It should be @branches by the way

Comment: i changed my answer.. be sure you get data in @branch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `<%= form_for [@product, @product.sold_histories.build, @branch = Branch.find(:all)] do |f| %>`

Change `@branch = Branch.find(:all)` to `@branch = Branch.all`

Edit: Why don't you place the @branch assignation inside the form block? Like this:

```
<%= form_for [@product, @product.sold_histories.build] do |f| %>
  <% @branch = Branch.find(:all) %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Comment: I get this error undefined method `to_key' for #<Branch::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fbce8b0a2a0> when I try this

Comment: I updated the answer, I'm not sure why you're putting the collection inside the form_for helper

Comment: Im doing this cause I want it to submit to the selected branch.. oh yh this actually works thanks!

Comment: how do you understand these rails syntax?

Comment: Experience xD. You should read more about the form helper, and routing. The array you're passing to the form_for helper is used to build the route that the form will POST to

Answer (score 0):

This might help you

```
<%= f.select :branch, options_for_select(@branch.collect {|a| [a.name, a.id]}) %>
```

You can get @branches in your controller action no need to write in form tag

Comment: I get this error undefined method `to_key' for #<Branch::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fbce8b0a2a0> when I try this

Comment: may be your @branch is nil.. put exit in your view. and check what data you get in your instace variable